# How to control behaviour of ActionMenuItem on long press?

Tags: android, androidx

The `ActionMenuItem`s when long pressed open a LinearLayout popup(inspected with Layout Inspector) with the `title` as text.

I have a simple one page app with Toolbar used as the action bar ( followed [this](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar) tutorial ).
I added few items to the action bar with this menu resource file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- "Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_favorite_24"
        android:title="@string/action_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- "Password", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_password"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_vpn_key_24"
        android:title="@string/action_password"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

When I long press the "Favourite" menu item, I get the following:  ( Notice the rectangular box just below action bar? )

[image: A rectangular pop-up with "Favourite" as text]

How do I prevent the popup OR modify the response?
Also, if i don't want to remove it, is it possible to change the theme of that popup?

Answer (score 0):

When you long press the icon, it shows whatever you define in `title` property, try to remove that property.

Comment: It works for items other than overflow item ( which shows "More Options" even though I did not set it). Also, this seems to be a workaround, and would break things if the item is displayed in overflow menu.  ( They're both set to display in action bar only if `ifRoom` is true.